# Extract data from dict in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm still struggling with extracting data in Ansible.

I have the following inventory:

```
---
all:
  children:
vms:
  hosts:
    vm1:
      services:
      - exim
      - apache
    vm2:
      services:
      - exim
      - nginx
    vm2:
      services:
      - exim
      - nginx
```

I defined the following variable:

```
services_parameters:
  nginx:
    log_files:
      - /var/log/nginx/*.log
    fail2ban_rules:
      nginx-limit-req:
      nginx-http-auth:
      nginx-botsearch:
      nginx-bad-request:
  exim:
    log_files:
      - /var/log/exim4/mainlog
    fail2ban_rules:
      exim:
      exim-spam:
  apache:
    log_files:
      - /var/log/apache2/*.log
    fail2ban_rules:
      apache-botsearch:
      apache-auth:
        parameters:
          logpath: /var/log/apache2/*.log
          findtime: 3600
          bantime: 86400
          maxretry: 3
      apache-badbots:
```

With

```
"{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].services | map('extract', services_parameters, 'fail2ban_rules') | combine }}"
```

I proudly managed to set a fact:

```
ok: [vm1] => {
    "fail2ban_rules": {
        "apache-auth": {
            "parameters": {
                "logpath": "/var/log/apache2/*.log"
            }
        },
        "apache-badbots": null,
        "apache-botsearch": null,
        "exim": null,
        "exim-spam": null
    }
}
ok: [vm2] => {
    "fail2ban_rules": {
        "exim": null,
        "exim-spam": null,
        "nginx-bad-request": null,
        "nginx-botsearch": null,
        "nginx-http-auth": null,
        "nginx-limit-req": null
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => {
    "fail2ban_rules": {
        "exim": null,
        "exim-spam": null,
        "nginx-bad-request": null,
        "nginx-botsearch": null,
        "nginx-http-auth": null,
        "nginx-limit-req": null
    }
}
```

So I can loop over to generate fail2ban rules.

Now I struggle to get all log_files to follow on each host, associated with the attached service, something like (manually written, may contain some typos):

```
ok: [vm1] => [
      {"exim": [
        "/var/log/exim4/mainlog"
        ]
      },
      {"apache": [
        "/var/log/apache2/*.log"
        ]
      }
]
ok: [vm2] => [
      {"exim": [
        "/var/log/exim4/mainlog"
        ]
      },
      {"nginx": [
        "/var/log/nginx/*.log"
        ]
      }
]
ok: [vm3] => [
      {"exim": [
        "/var/log/exim4/mainlog"
        ]
      },
      {"nginx": [
        "/var/log/nginx/*.log"
        ]
      }
]
```

With this fact I will loop over the services to generate block like:

```
nginx:
  paths:
    - /var/log/nginx/*.log
    - <other paths if defined in services_parameters variable>
```

There is probably a workaround, but this is a good example of the recurrent painful data manipulation I face since using Ansible.

Comment: In the above, note that `hostvars[inventory_hostname].services` is a complex and totally unneeded alias to the much simpler `services`.

Comment: Thanks! services_parameters used to be named services as well as the inventory variable, I found this workaround to avoid abiguity. This is a leftover.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following `inventory.yml`

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    services_parameters:
      nginx:
        log_files:
          - /var/log/nginx/*.log
        fail2ban_rules:
          nginx-limit-req:
          nginx-http-auth:
          nginx-botsearch:
          nginx-bad-request:
      exim:
        log_files:
          - /var/log/exim4/mainlog
        fail2ban_rules:
          exim:
          exim-spam:
      apache:
        log_files:
          - /var/log/apache2/*.log
        fail2ban_rules:
          apache-botsearch:
          apache-auth:
            parameters:
              logpath: /var/log/apache2/*.log
              findtime: 3600
              bantime: 86400
              maxretry: 3
          apache-badbots:
vms:
  hosts:
    vm1:
      services:
        - exim
        - apache
    vm2:
      services:
        - exim
        - nginx
    vm3:
      services:
        - apache
        - nginx
```

the following self explanatory `playbook.yml` contains some data manipulation and possible loops to acheive what you need (from what I understood)

```yaml
---
- name: Debug service params for each host
  hosts: vms
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    services_list: >- 
      {{ 
        services_parameters 
        | dict2items(key_name='service_name', value_name='service_parameters')
        | selectattr('service_name', 'in', services)
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: Show service list for each target server
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: services_list

    - name: loop over a consolidated list of fail2ban rules for each target
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ services_list | map(attribute='service_parameters.fail2ban_rules') | combine | dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"

    - name: loop over each log file keeping the relevant service name
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }} is a log file of service {{ item.0.service_name }}"
      loop: "{{ services_list | subelements('service_parameters.log_files') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1 }}"
```

Demo run

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook.yml 

PLAY [Debug service params for each host] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show service list for each target server] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm1] => {
    "services_list": [
        {
            "service_name": "exim",
            "service_parameters": {
                "fail2ban_rules": {
                    "exim": null,
                    "exim-spam": null
                },
                "log_files": [
                    "/var/log/exim4/mainlog"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "service_name": "apache",
            "service_parameters": {
                "fail2ban_rules": {
                    "apache-auth": {
                        "parameters": {
                            "bantime": 86400,
                            "findtime": 3600,
                            "logpath": "/var/log/apache2/*.log",
                            "maxretry": 3
                        }
                    },
                    "apache-badbots": null,
                    "apache-botsearch": null
                },
                "log_files": [
                    "/var/log/apache2/*.log"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
ok: [vm2] => {
    "services_list": [
        {
            "service_name": "nginx",
            "service_parameters": {
                "fail2ban_rules": {
                    "nginx-bad-request": null,
                    "nginx-botsearch": null,
                    "nginx-http-auth": null,
                    "nginx-limit-req": null
                },
                "log_files": [
                    "/var/log/nginx/*.log"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "service_name": "exim",
            "service_parameters": {
                "fail2ban_rules": {
                    "exim": null,
                    "exim-spam": null
                },
                "log_files": [
                    "/var/log/exim4/mainlog"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
ok: [vm3] => {
    "services_list": [
        {
            "service_name": "nginx",
            "service_parameters": {
                "fail2ban_rules": {
                    "nginx-bad-request": null,
                    "nginx-botsearch": null,
                    "nginx-http-auth": null,
                    "nginx-limit-req": null
                },
                "log_files": [
                    "/var/log/nginx/*.log"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "service_name": "apache",
            "service_parameters": {
                "fail2ban_rules": {
                    "apache-auth": {
                        "parameters": {
                            "bantime": 86400,
                            "findtime": 3600,
                            "logpath": "/var/log/apache2/*.log",
                            "maxretry": 3
                        }
                    },
                    "apache-badbots": null,
                    "apache-botsearch": null
                },
                "log_files": [
                    "/var/log/apache2/*.log"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

TASK [loop over a consolidated list of fail2ban rules for each target] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm1] => (item=exim) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "exim",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=nginx-limit-req) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-limit-req",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm1] => (item=exim-spam) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "exim-spam",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=nginx-limit-req) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-limit-req",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=nginx-http-auth) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-http-auth",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm1] => (item=apache-botsearch) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "apache-botsearch",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=nginx-http-auth) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-http-auth",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=nginx-botsearch) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-botsearch",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm1] => (item=apache-auth) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "apache-auth",
        "value": {
            "parameters": {
                "bantime": 86400,
                "findtime": 3600,
                "logpath": "/var/log/apache2/*.log",
                "maxretry": 3
            }
        }
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=nginx-botsearch) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-botsearch",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm1] => (item=apache-badbots) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "apache-badbots",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=nginx-bad-request) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-bad-request",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=nginx-bad-request) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "nginx-bad-request",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=exim) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "exim",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=apache-botsearch) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "apache-botsearch",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=exim-spam) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "exim-spam",
        "value": null
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=apache-auth) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "apache-auth",
        "value": {
            "parameters": {
                "bantime": 86400,
                "findtime": 3600,
                "logpath": "/var/log/apache2/*.log",
                "maxretry": 3
            }
        }
    }
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=apache-badbots) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "apache-badbots",
        "value": null
    }
}

TASK [loop over each log file keeping the relevant service name] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm1] => (item=/var/log/exim4/mainlog) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/exim4/mainlog is a log file of service exim"
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=/var/log/nginx/*.log) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/nginx/*.log is a log file of service nginx"
}
ok: [vm1] => (item=/var/log/apache2/*.log) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/apache2/*.log is a log file of service apache"
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=/var/log/exim4/mainlog) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/exim4/mainlog is a log file of service exim"
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=/var/log/nginx/*.log) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/nginx/*.log is a log file of service nginx"
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=/var/log/apache2/*.log) => {
    "msg": "/var/log/apache2/*.log is a log file of service apache"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
vm1                        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm2                        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm3                        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```